# How to set Item Widget if Item was not yet addet to TreeWidget using .addTopLevelItem()

Tags: python, pyqt

Each column item of `QTreeWidgetItem` is populated with `QComboBox`.

So let's say I create an `QTreeWidgetItem`:

```
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
treeItem=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
tree.addTopLevelItem(treeItem) 

for i in range(10):
    tree.setItemWidget(item, i, QtGui.QComboBox())
```

Now if I comment out `tree.addTopLevelItem(treeItem)` no comboboxes will be added to the QTreeWidgetItem. By other words, I have to add `QTreeWidgetItem` to Tree in order to be able to add `QComboBox`es to `QTreeWidgetItem`. But at the time `QTreeWidgetItem` is created I don't know if it is going to be a `topLevelItem' or if it will be added to another topLevelItem as a child item using`.appendRow()` method.

Should I just go ahead and assign this item to the Tree as a topLevel and then reassign it as a child? What method should I use to make a topLevelItem a child item of another top level item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have many way to create data in `QTreeWidget` in my favorite way to create, I have use constructor of `QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem` to link it too root item with out using `QTreeWidget.addTopLevelItem` and suggest not use it.

Example like this;

```
myQTreeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
listsHeader = ['A', 'B', 'C']
myQTreeWidget.setHeaderItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(listsHeader))
dataQTreeWidgetItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(myQTreeWidget) # assgin QTreeWidget
for i in range(len(listsHeader)):
    dataQTreeWidgetItem.setText(0, 'INDEX ' + str(i)) # Test text in column
    myQTreeWidget.setItemWidget(dataQTreeWidgetItem, i, QtGui.QComboBox())
```

**Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidgetitem.html#QTreeWidgetItem-3

---

**EDITED 0:50 7/8/2014**
Add header in list.

---

Regards,

Comment: I forget something, It can be set header. Please read my edited answer again. thanks.